# When do liquibase changeSets get run in parallel?

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

Because of a service refactor I had a big liquibase migration running. Sadly, the migration ran into multiple deadlocks on the way even though the script on local and staging ran OK.

This lead me to question, does liquibase run changeSets in parallel at some point? I expected it to run sequentially, one after another as specified in the `changelog`.

As the migration is run on Spring Application Startup it's too early for hibernate to interfere, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: No, Liquibase does not run changesets in paralel (as of my decent knowledge on the subject). Changesets are executed in the order they are defined within a changelog and the changelogs are executed in whatever order you instruct in the mainchangelog.
It helps to have a root cause idea if you could provide some specific error examples here.

Comment: One other thing to mention, at a particular point in time, only one Liquibase update/deploy can be executed. This is made possible by Liquibase setting (and releasing after deploy completion) a lock in databasechangeloglock table (locked column). This means no two sessions/processes can run changesets against a target database in the same time (not in parallel).

Comment: Thank you! I think need to improve my question and dig more into liquibase locking. What I want to figure out is why these deadlocks happened during DB migration with liquibase. But for now it's finding the right question to ask.